# How to access value of the input box surrounded by ion-input directive

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic3, angular-directive, mobile-application

I am new to Ionic. I am using Ionic framework 3. My problem is that I don't know how to access the input value which is surrounded by ion-input directive. I want to access the value of the input box for my custom directive which I created.

Will ElementRef be helpful to get the value of input box? I tried it but failed. Please guide me the right way to access the value of the input box in the custom directive. Below is my code...

**My custom directive code** - *phonenumber*

```
import { Directive, HostListener, ElementRef } from '@angular/core';

/**
 * Generated class for the PhonenumberDirective directive.
 *
 * See https://angular.io/api/core/Directive for more info on Angular
 * Directives.
 */
@Directive({
  selector: '[phonenumber]' // Attribute selector
})
export class PhonenumberDirective {

  constructor(private element: ElementRef) {
    console.log('Hello PhonenumberDirective Directive');
  }

  @HostListener('keydown', ['$event']) onkeydown(event) {
    let inputValue = this.element.nativeElement.textContent;
    // Here inputValue is undefined I am getting :-(
  }

}
```

**HTML Code**

```
<ion-list inset>
    <ion-item>
        <ion-label floating>Mobile Number</ion-label>
        <ion-input clearInput name="username" id="loginField" type="tel" required [(ngModel)]="lusername" #username="ngModel"  maxlength="10" phonenumber></ion-input>
    </ion-item>
    <div [hidden]="username.valid || username.pristine" class="alert alert-danger">
            Mobile number is required
    </div>
</ion-list>
```

Comment: let inputElement = this.element.getElementsByTagName('input')[0];

Comment: @Jamie, thank you for your response. I tried your answer before. But that is upto accessing input element, not to get the value inside of it.

Comment: @SivakumarTadisetti i am not understanding you question

Comment: Hi @MohanGopi, I have created one custom directive named phonenumber and assigned that to one of my input field in my form. So whenever user performs keydown event I want to access the entire input present in the input box. But I am getting undefined as you can see in my code posted along with question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
import { Directive, HostListener, ElementRef } from '@angular/core';

@Directive({
  selector: '[phonenumber]' // Attribute selector
})
export class PhonenumberDirective {

  inputElement: any; 
  constructor(private element: ElementRef) {
    console.log('Hello PhonenumberDirective Directive');
  }

  @HostListener('keydown', ['$event']) onkeydown(event) {
    this.inputElement = this.element.nativeElement.getElementsByTagName('input')[0];
    console.log(this.inputElement.value)
  }

}
```

Get the input and then access the value from that.

You might also want **keyup**

```
 @HostListener('keyup', ['$event']) onkeydown(event)
```

To  get the latest value, but that depends on your needs.

Comment: Thanks @Jamie, your answer became the solution to my problem. And yes, keyup also helped me to get the latest value